# Run JavaScript safely on the Server using V8?

Tags: security, v8

Is there a custom build of V8 that isolates it from the Operating System?
Similar to Node.js but without access to system calls.

It seems that it should be possible to use it for safe JavaScript execution on the Server. It's used in Browser and Browsers designed to run dangerous code safely.

So technically it seems it should be possible to isolate V8 from the Operating System in the similar way it's done in Browser and use for safe script execution.

It wouldn't prevent from endless loop or endless memory consumption, but it should prevent from dangerous code getting access to the system.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed V8 itself (without Node.js) into any application, and scripts running within it would have no access to anything other than standard JavaScript built-ins unless you explicitly provided such access.

Be aware however that V8 crashes its process whenever it hits various limits, some of which aren't under your control, so if you're using it to run untrusted scripts, you'll have to make sure your application can withstand such crashes. That means it'll probably need a Chrome-like multi-process design.